# responsive tables in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the following `jsfiddle` code work. Actually all is working fine, for server side i am using ColdFusion.

the values are appearing 6 in a row. the 6 is hard-coded in ColdFusion variables, so it splits the values in 6 and then next row.

Now i want to make this a responsive so it should work with tablets and mobile devices without much pain in the a****s

Here is the fiddle i had generated

http://jsfiddle.net/9arpxvga/

This needs a help in implementation of responsive design...

A Jquery, javascript solution will also work

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201874/responsive-table-containing-images-in-html-and-css?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to be hard-pressed to find an objective solution to such a broad question. So, broadly: *one of* the many ways to implement responsive design is to write CSS media queries, targeting various screen sizes. Here's an example snippet taken from getskeleton.com (which might be worth checking out if you need a bare-bones responsive framework to get you started)

```
    /* #Media Queries
================================================== */

  /* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

  /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

  /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

  /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

  /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

You'd just write new CSS (or override your css) for each of the screen sizes you're trying to target. (Nest your css within the brackets after each media screen). Hope that helps.